# Weird Linux and/or MagSafe charger glitch

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power, magsafe

This is... confusing to say the least.

A few months ago, the battery in my 2010/2011 MacBook Pro completely died, complete with a Permanent Failure Flag.
Today, I replaced it, and things are really weird now.

After I replaced the battery, the computer no longer has to be jump started, which is good.

When I connect the MagSafe charger, the light on the charger remains off. Putting my ear up to the charger reveals that the AC to DC converter is active and that the charger is putting out voltage. The charger and the MagSafe connector gets warm. Xubuntu 16.04 LTS indicates that when the computer is not connected to power, the battery is discharging. When I connect power, it seems to hang around for a minute or so, then says that the battery is fully charged at 50%, and the entire time, the light on the MagSafe charger is off. I've reset the SMC and zapped the PRAM/NVRAM to no avail.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Does AHT say anything?

Comment: The MacBook has Linux on it.

Comment: That's... unfortunate.  However, read https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25696?locale=en_US

Comment: @TheComputerGeek010101001 You should still be able to run AHT. If it turns out you did manage to wipe it off your drive entirely, [you can create a bootable volume with AHT on it.](https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest)